# AspNetCore NodeServices throws NodeInvocationException

Tags: node.js, asp.net-core, jsrender, jsreport, javascriptservices

I am using NodeServices to create PDF in AspNetCore app. App works fine on local machine but when deployed on production, on calling the pdf function, I get the following error:

> Error: spawn D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\phantomjs\lib\phantom\bin\phantomjs ENOENT
>       at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19) at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:372:16)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.NodeInvocationException: Error during rendering report: spawn D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\phantomjs\lib\phantom\bin\phantomjs ENOENT
>
> Error: spawn D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\phantomjs\lib\phantom\bin\phantomjs ENOENT 
>   at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19) at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:372:16)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

I verified that all the files are at their right place. `node_modules` are present in the deployment.

Node Version on Azure: 8.9.4

Code to generate PDF:

```
module.exports = function (callback, html) {
var jsreport = require('jsreport-core')();

jsreport.init().then(function () {
    return jsreport.render({
        template: {
            content: html,
            engine: 'jsrender',
            recipe: 'phantom-pdf'
        }
    }).then(function (resp) {
        callback(/* error */ null, resp.content.toJSON().data);
    }).catch(function (e) {
        callback(/* error */ e, null);
    });
}).catch(function (e) {
    callback(/* error */ e, null);
});
};
```

Comment: How are you importing the node module?

Comment: I followed exact procedure as mentioned here:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-export-HTML-to-PDF-c5afd0ce

`var jsreport = require('jsreport-core')(); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the installation of Node packages. I was using Hosted Linux on Azure to build the solution. Switched to Hosted VS2017 build and everything is working smoothly.
https://github.com/pofider/phantom-html-to-pdf/issues/68

Comment: there is a permission issue, when installing phantom.js. you could like to try "sudo npm install  --unsafe-perm".

Answer (score 0):

If you use Azure App Service with a free plan, you cannot render pdf on the server. This is because the service runs in a sandbox and thus cannot run third-party executables, like node.exe. You need to upgrade your service's plan to 'Basic' or higher.

Comment: I am on Pay-as-you-go plan.